# How to have a pop-up window for password appear when opening application?

Tags: permissions, window-manager, gui, wireshark

We have build `wireshark` adding some functionality related to our use, in Scientific Linux 6 system.

After this when I start this using normal user, it will not allow me to use the network interface. I have to login via root to do the same.

Is there any way that when I click on `wireshark`, and before the application starts a GUI will appear asking for the password for root? The same as when we open `Firewall`.

Can I do this using a shell script?

Comment: Use `gksudo`, the GTK+ frontend for `sudo`.

Comment: Any particular distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please* do **NOT** run Wireshark as root.  Much/most of the large body of wireshark code does not need to (and should not) run as root. There's over 1M lines of code !

If a user is to be allowed to run Wireshark to do network captures, only the separate dumpcap program (which does the actual captures) needs special privileges.

See:

wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireshark

wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges

wiki.wireshark.org/Security

(Also: a simple google search may help).

Comment: I totally agree. Take a look at CVE database of software vulnerabilities for wireshark bugs. There are few security bugs detected in wireshark every month.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command `visudo` you can add a rule so that others can run `wireshark` using elevated credentials as root, without having to do too much work.

```
$ visudo
```

And add this rule to the end:

```
someuser ALL=/usr/bin/wireshark
```

Save this file and you should be able to invoke `wireshark` and get a a GUI dialog asking for the password with this command:

```
$ gksudo wireshark
```

#### References

- [Allow A Normal User To Run Commands As root Under Linux / UNIX Operating Systems](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/allow-a-normal-user-to-run-commands-as-root.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason why you cannot be added to the 'wireshark' group?

For instance, if you had sudo rights with your own account you could run

```
sudo usermod --append -G wireshark $USER
```

I think this is the approach recommended by the project.

*You will likely need to logout/login for changes to take effect.